# PHP, SQLite on windows using doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sqlite

i must connect to sqlite db file using doctrine,
when i copy db file to php(composer) project i can easily connect to DB,
but when i try to make absolute path it says `SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`

i'm using symfony4.2 project for it and doctrine2.5

my .env is like this

```
DATABASE_WSW="sqlite:////C:\\Program Files\\programX\\db.sqlite" or
DATABASE_WSW="sqlite:////C:\Program Files\programX\db.sqlite" or
DATABASE_WSW="sqlite:////C:/Program Files/programX/db.sqlite"
```

above examples don't work

when used like this works:

```
DATABASE_WSW=sqlite:///db.sqlite
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bloody spaces in path. does `DATABASE_WSW="sqlite:////C:\\Program~1\\programX\\db.sqlite"` (or ~2) work?

Comment: @Cid no it doesn't work

Comment: I guess your DB path should be relative to the base directory of the web application.

Comment: but why absolute path is not working :(

Comment: relative worked